# Adding ordihulls to a CCA triplot

Tags: vegan

I have recently completed a CCA composed of 40 grass species and 14 environmental variables on separate matrices at 75 different sites. I would now like to visually group the species based on their position on the CCA ordination plot. I used the 'vegan' package on R studio, and assume the Ordihull tool would be used to create 'circles' around the desired groups. Is this possible on a CCA?

Comment: CCA is (in this case) canonical correspondence analysis. As this isn't a statistical question, it is OT here. A better place would be on [so] or in the Discussions at the GitHub repo for the vegan package https://github.com/vegandevs/vegan/discussions

Comment: Yes. It is possible. See the documentation of ordihull.

Comment: Naturally, ordihull() does not draw circles but convex hulls (like could be guessed from its name). There is no tool to draw circles in vegan: vegan is not that primitive. However, you can draw enclosing ellipses with ordiellipse(). As usual, check its documentation.